# InvalidRegistration when sending message to device via GCM

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send a GCM message to my device, and for some reason, on the server, the getErrorCodeName() is returning InvalidRegisration.

I basically implemented the example from google, and registered, and sent the registration ID to the log, and wholesale copied it from the log to the code on the server where I am trying to do the send.

Any idea on what could be wrong?

```
        Result result = sender.send(message,"foo", 1);
        System.out.println("Message sent: "+result.getErrorCodeName());
```

I have double checked to see that logcat is not truncating the value being printed out, and it isn't. I logged the length of the registration id and matched it with the length of the string/regid I'm using on the server when I am sending the notification.

Not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

The `send()` method has to follow this format:

```
send (Message message, String registrationId, int retries)
```

Looking at your snippet of code, you will need to revise the second parameter.

If you had just replaced the actual registration ID for privacy reasons, I would suggest checking that you are sending the registration ID completely. As mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html#error_codes), it could have been truncated or altered in transit from your client device to your server.

Comment: Of course foo is just a made up parameter for purposes of the question. Give me more credit than that :-/

Comment: That did cross my mind. Which is why that was only half the solution I proposed.